# reading optional chaining issue?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I am getting the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
    let imageString = self.thumblist1[indexPath.item]
    let imageUrl = URL(string: imageString)
    let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl!)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if (imageData != nil)
        {
            cell2?.verticalImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        }
    }
}

return cell2!
```

Comment: Which line exactly is crashing? You have 3 crash operators (`!`) in the code you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your `imageUrl` is not nil before call the `image`:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {

let imageString = self.thumblist1[indexPath.item]
if let imageUrl = URL(string: imageString) {
    let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if (imageData != nil)
        {
            cell2?.verticalImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        }
    }
}

}
 return cell2!
 }
```